# Vulkan API не возвращает расширения и слои валидации

Tags: c++, windows, vulkan

При попытке получения свойств слоёв валидации и расширений в вектора типа VkLayerProperties и VkExtensionProperties, функции VkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties и VkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties возвращают только количество слоёв и расширений, а число элементов в векторах = 0.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int wmain() {

//////////////////// Слои ////////////////////

        uint32_t lCount = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(
            &lCount,
            nullptr);

        if (lCount == 0)
            std::cout << "Error: Validation layers is missing !" << std::endl;

        std::vector<VkLayerProperties> lProperties;
        vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(
            &lCount,
            lProperties.data());

        std::cout << "Layers count : " << lCount << std::endl;
        std::for_each(lProperties.begin(), lProperties.end(), [](VkLayerProperties& prop) {
            std::cout << prop.layerName << std::endl;
        });

//////////////////// Расширения ////////////////////

        uint32_t exCount = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
            nullptr,
            &exCount,
            nullptr);

        if (exCount == 0)
            std::cout << "Error: Extensions is missing !" << std::endl;

        std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> exProperties;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
            nullptr,
            &exCount,
            exProperties.data());

        std::cout << "Extension count : " << exCount << std::endl;
        std::for_each(exProperties.begin(), exProperties.end(), [](VkExtensionProperties& prop) {
            std::cout << prop.extensionName << std::endl;
        });

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я не понимаю о каком загрузчике идёт речь

Comment: В первый раз слышу о таком. Вообще я читал книжку "Vulkan API - Руководство разработчика" и там ни о каком загрузчике не говорилось.

Comment: Да там просто передается пустой вектор, не понятно как ТС вообще ждет что туда что-то запишется, т.к. я думаю `data()` будет возвращать `end()` или `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что необходимо делать `std::vector<>::resize` перд тем как передавать `std::vector<>::resize::data` в си функцию. Она откуда может знать, выделена ли там память или нет?

```
uint32_t lCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(
    &lCount,
    nullptr);

if (lCount == 0)
    std::cout << "Error: Validation layers is missing !" << std::endl;

std::vector<VkLayerProperties> lProperties;
lProperties.resize(lCount);
vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(
    &lCount,
    lProperties.data());

std::cout << "Layers count : " << lCount << std::endl;
std::for_each(lProperties.begin(), lProperties.end(), [](VkLayerProperties& prop) {
    std::cout << prop.layerName << std::endl;
    });

//////////////////// Расширения ////////////////////

uint32_t exCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
    nullptr,
    &exCount,
    nullptr);

if (exCount == 0)
    std::cout << "Error: Extensions is missing !" << std::endl;

std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> exProperties;
exProperties.resize(exCount)
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
    nullptr,
    &exCount,
    exProperties.data());

std::cout << "Extension count : " << exCount << std::endl;
std::for_each(exProperties.begin(), exProperties.end(), [](VkExtensionProperties& prop) {
    std::cout << prop.extensionName << std::endl;
    });
```

До исправления:

```
Layers count : 10
Extension count : 11
```

После исправления:

```
Layers count : 10
VK_LAYER_AMD_switchable_graphics
VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay
VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_fossilize
VK_MIRILLIS_LAYER
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_simulation
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_gfxreconstruct
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot
Extension count : 11
VK_KHR_device_group_creation
VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities
VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities
VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities
VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2
VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
VK_KHR_surface
VK_KHR_win32_surface
VK_EXT_debug_report
VK_EXT_debug_utils
VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace
```

P.S. не знаю с какого стандарта это пошло, но при пустом векторе, при попытке обращения к `.data()` или же к `&someVector[0]` вернется `NULL`.